# Histograms changing shape when specifying new color aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run

```
ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=price, y=..density.., 
                          color=cut, fill=cut)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha=.25, bins=30)+ 
  facet_wrap(~cut)
```

I get:

[image: histograms]

a histograms with a very different shape than I get when I specify a new color aesthetic:

```
carat_levs <- c(0, quantile(diamonds$carat))
diamonds$carat_fac <- factor(cut(diamonds$carat, carat_levs), ordered=TRUE)

ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=price, y=..density.., 
                          color=carat_fac, fill=carat_fac)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha=.25, bins=30) + 
  facet_wrap(~cut)
```

which gives me this plot:

[image: this plot]

The difference is clearest in the first facet, but there are differences in all facets.

If I delete the `y=..density..` mapping, the discrepancy appears to go away.

Can anyone shed light on this?  Is the `..density..` argument being applied to the new color mapping as well or something?  Is there a way to recover the original density histogram shapes with the coloring?

Comment: The densities are calculated per group and integrate to 1, which are automatically implied by different fill categories. Having multiple groups in a panel means that every group integrates to 1, instead of the entire panel integrating to 1.